# Inconvenientes con Middleware FluentValidation con MediatR C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dapper, cqrs

tengo el siguiente inconveniente con el ValidationMiddleware de fluentvalidation con mediatR, resulta que implemente esta clase, para que me valide si la petición que estoy enviando a través de mediatR cumple las reglas de validación o no, pero cuando envió la petición por postman no me entra al ValidationMiddleware y no se porque si instale los paquetes Nuggets necesarios, pero no me funciona, la clase ValidationMiddleware que tengo es la siguiente,

```
    public class ValidationMiddleware<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse> where TResponse : BaseResponse<object>
    {
    private readonly IValidator<TRequest>? _validator;

    public ValidationMiddleware(IValidator<TRequest>? validator = null)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_validator is null) 
        {
            return await next();
        }

        ValidationResult validatorResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (validatorResult.IsValid) 
        {
            return await next();
        }

        BaseResponse<object> response = new BaseResponse<object>
        {
            IsSuccess = false,
            Errors = validatorResult.Errors.Select(error => new BaseError
            {
                PropertyName = error.PropertyName,
                ErrorMessage = error.ErrorMessage
            }).ToList(),
            Message = "Errores de validacion",
        };

        return (TResponse)response;
    }
}
```

y esta son los servicios que estoy registrando en mi clase program,

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInjectionApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMediatR(x => x.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationMiddleware<,>));

    return services;
}
```

Este es mi clase BaseResponse,

```
public class BaseResponse<T>
{
    #region Properties
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public T? Data { get; set; }
    public string? Message { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BaseError>? Errors { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

y esta es mi clase base errors

```
public class BaseError
{
    #region Properties
    public string? PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Estas es mi clase validator donde tengo las reglas de validacion del modelo con FluentValidation, que es el siguiente,

```
public class CreateGenderValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateGenderCommand>
{
    #region Constructors
    public CreateGenderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.GenderId)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("El campo Codigo no puede ser nulo.")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo Codigo no puede ser vacio.")
            .MaximumLength(1).WithMessage("La cantidad de caracteres permitidos, para el campo Codigo es de 1 caracter.");

        RuleFor(x => x.GenderName)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("El campo Genero no puede ser nulo.")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo Genero no puede ser vacio.")
            .MaximumLength(10).WithMessage("La cantidad de caracteres permitidos, para el campo Genero son 10 caracteres.");

        RuleFor(x => x.CreateBy)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("El campo Creado Por no puede ser nulo.")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("El campo Creado Por no puede ser vacio.")
            .EmailAddress().WithMessage("En el campo Creado Por se debe de ingresar un correo electronico valido.")
            .MaximumLength(60).WithMessage("La cantidad de caracteres permitidos, para el campo Creado por son 60 caracteres.");

        RuleFor(x => x.CreationDate)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("El campo Fecha de Creacion no puede ser nulo.");

        RuleFor(x => x.ModifiedDate)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("El campo Fecha de Modificacion no puede ser nulo.");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

y no me entra a las validaciones,no se que me faltaria o que estoy haciendo mal, agradeceria la ayuda